# Cost of Initializing jQuery Sortable Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently working on a form builder and using jQuery sortable the issue I am having is removing the event handler from the a list item when the current field is being edited. And then re-initializing it after the question input is saved.

Currently I am running the initialization of jQuery Sortable.

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
         placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
         items : ".is-sortable"
    });
```

then running the destroy method when editing to remove the sortable functionality

```
$('.sortable').sortable('destroy');
```

and then on save of the question re-initializing sortable.

```
 $('.sortable').sortable({
         placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
         items : ".is-sortable"
    });
```

I tried adding and removing the .is-sortable class to prevent sorting if the class is not there but since the event handler is attached to the parent container the the item is still sortable

Is there a better approach to this to unbind the event handler on jQuery sortable

and if not is what is the cost of destroying and re-initializing the plugin on each "Add, "Edit" and, "Save" of a field.

Comment: I would suggest instead of manipulating the sortable to add a new `isediting` class of your own during edit, and then make your listener `$('.sortable:not(.isediting)').sortable( . . . );`

Comment: @briansol I just gave that a shot but it did not work the event handler still allows for moving the field even when the is-editing class is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cancel` method instead of `destroy`. The cancel method stops the current sort operation.

> Cancels a change in the current sortable and reverts it to the state prior to when the current sort was started. Useful in the stop and receive callback functions.

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel

Now cancel the operation on editing. I think, this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have enable and disable that could do the work also, then you wouldn't have to recall it everytime:

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-disable